# ionViewDidEnter not called on page refesh

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using loader service to show loader on `ionViewWillEnter` and hide loader on `ionViewDidEnter`. Everything works fine when I move to the page via route but when I refresh the same page `ionViewDidEnter` is not called and hence loader is stuck.

Comment: how you refreshing the app can you put your code?

Comment: using browser refresh button

Comment: Means reload right ?

Answer (score 0):

In ionic you can use [angular life cycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) `ngOnInit()` or `ngAfterViewInit()` might help you

Comment: angular life cycle hooks wont get called when using ionic navigation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

i normally use the `ngOnInit` hook and it works 
you should try it. but be sure to get rid of the

```
@ionicPage()
```

decorator, since you are using an angular hook,
else it probably wont work

```
ngOnInit(){
....
}
```

works for me, i hope it does for you.